# Extracting dates and changing their format in R

Tags: r, date

I have a vector of dates in this format:

```
dates

20-Jun-91
8-Mar-89
14-Sep-96
19-Dec-00

3-Feb-95
25-Jul-92
```

I want to extract their years and add them to another column:

```
new dates

1991
1989
1996
2000
NA
1995
1992
```

Any date that is not in the format d-M-y should be read as NA.

strptime seems to work only if the dates are all numerical.

Any ideas?

Thank you all!

Comment: Study `help("strptime")` in more detail and `help("as.Date")` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
strptime(df$dates, "%d-%b-%y")$year + 1900
```

Using `lubridate` package:

```
year(dmy(df$dates))
```

Comment: Credit is due to both @DavidArenburg and zx8754 for their very helpful edit of my original answer ^ ^